# how to sort some of tuples in a list by a parameter if the whloe list is sorted by other parameter in python

Tags: python

i want to sort a list of tuples that first parameter is name and second is the grade. for example:

```
list_of_grades=[('ali', 5), ('mendy', 7.5), ('hani', 7.5), ('sara', 7.5), ('sol', 7.8333), ('arvin', 11.375)]
```

i sorted them by grades. i want to sort the similar grades by names too. in this example three 7.5 should be sorted alphabetically(first hani then mendy and at last sara). but i can't sort the list by name because then the grades get unsorted. help me!

Comment: What did your searches in stackoverflow reveal about sorting lists of tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sorted:

```
sorted(list_of_grades,key=lambda x:(x[1],x[0]))
```

Explanation:
First we are using lambda function with argument '1', to sort by 2nd element of tuple, and then with '0', to sort further by 1st element.